# Jetty 9 stop port and key in command line arguments

Tags: jetty, command-line-arguments

In Jetty 8 I was passing values like `-Djetty.port=8888 -DSTOP.PORT=8887 -DSTOP.KEY=STOP` but in Jetty 9 these don't seem to work.

I am able to set the port with `--module=http jetty.port=8888` but am not sure how to set the other values?

Also, I used to use the command `java -DSTOP.PORT=8887 -DSTOP.KEY=STOP -jar start.jar --stop` but am not sure how to run the stop command now?

The docs at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/start-jar.html#d0e8360 suggest that stopping hasn't changed, but when I try that I get

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.stop(Main.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.stop(Main.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
   java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
```

TIA

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem, but found it has always been an overlooked mistake on my part.  With that being said, I think you are actually on the right track.

## This should work

With
jetty-distribution-9.2.7.v20150116
the following sequence does work:

```
# setting up jetty config
java -jar mypath/start.jar  --add-to-startd=http,deploy

# check to see if the ports are available
netstat -tapn | grep "808[07]"

# starting server
java -DSTOP.PORT=8087 -DSTOP.KEY=STOP -jar mypath/start.jar

# check to see if the ports are now monitored
netstat -tapn | grep "808[07]"

# starting server
java -DSTOP.PORT=8087 -DSTOP.KEY=STOP -jar mypath/start.jar --stop

# check to see if the ports are now free
netstat -tapn | grep "808[07]"
```

## Preferred syntax

The above -D syntax works, but the following syntax is better supported:

```
java -jar mypath/start.jar STOP.PORT=8087 STOP.KEY=STOP
java -jar mypath/start.jar STOP.PORT=8087 STOP.KEY=STOP --stop
java -jar mypath/start.jar STOP.PORT=8087 STOP.KEY=STOP --list-config
java -jar mypath/start.jar STOP.PORT=8087 STOP.KEY=STOP --dry-run
```

You can easily confirm that this syntax does work by trying it.

## Additional steps

Those last two commands (--list-config and --dry-run) can be very handy for checking a variety of problems.

The --help command is also very useful to sanity checking odd problems like this.  It does reveal nuances like the above preferred syntax that you found difficult to find:

```
java -jar mypath/start.jar --help
```

If you've already tried these steps, try upgrading to a newer version of Jetty in case the problem you experienced was an actually bug that was subsequently fixed.

If it still doesn't work, I'll try to help you and update this "answer" appropriately.